# Dynamic function calls in Python using XMLRPC

Tags: python, function, xml-rpc, rpc

I'm writing a class which I intend to use to create subroutines, constructor as following:

```
def __init__(self,menuText,RPC_params,RPC_call):
   #Treat the params
   #Call the given RPC_call with the treated params
```

The problem is that I want to call the function on the pattern "**rpc.serve.(function name here)(params)**",
where rpc is a serverProxy object that I'm using to call XMLRPC functions, and serve.-function name- is the method I'm calling on the XMLRPC-server.

I've looked at [Calling a function from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python), but seeing how my serverProxy object doesnt know which "remote attributes" it have, I cant use the getattr() function to retrieve the method.

I've seen a example by making a dictionary to call a given function, but is there no way to make the function truly dynamic by creating the function call as you would create a String?
Like running a String as a function?

Comment: Why do you want this pattern? why not rpc.functionName(params)?

Comment: If you mean why I added "serve" ,its just for logical grouping of functions on the server, and nothing functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `getattr` to get the function name from the server proxy, so calling the function like this will work:

```
getattr(rpc, function_name)(*params)
```

Comment: You're right! Didnt know. But I still would like to know if its possible to run a given String as a method without using  getattr() though. Even when I see the obvious pro's of using the getattr() method.

Comment: You could "run the string" via eval or exec, but that would be supremely [expletive deleted], with no advantage at all wrt getattr and more disadvantages than you can shake a stick at.